# How do I get the Macantosh HD directory to show up in the favorites sidebar in Finder for Mountain Lion?

Tags: osx-mountain-lion

One of the things that is annoying me about Mountain Lion is that I have to go to disk utility just to access the hard disk directory. Is there any way to make the hard disk directory show up in the favorites sidebar on the finder in Mountain Lion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to Finder's preferences, and under *Sidebar*, select *Hard disks*:

[image]

Your Macintosh HD will now show up in the sidebar.